# Unhandled .net error while creating an item using insert from template

Tags: installation

I have installed Sitecore 9 on Windows 8.1. While trying to create a new item from a template I am getting the error below
An unhandled Microsoft .net Framework exception occurred in w3wp.exe [12500]

Once i click on insert from template the popup opens to select the template but once i click on the folder the microsoft error dialog box appears and everything get stuck. I am not able to get anything in the logs
Event log:

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.5.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x5215df96
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.7.2053.0, time stamp: 0x58fa6d2a
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x000000000004c578
Faulting process id: 0x30d4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d396d22a080967
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: a744213e-02c5-11e8-837f-801934b0cd1c
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

And below is the log i am getting in debug diagnostic

```
System.Exception    1    <none>    ; 
System.OutOfMemoryException    1    <none>    ; 
System.StackOverflowException    1    <none>    ; 
System.ExecutionEngineException    1    <none>    ; 
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException    2    <none>    ; 
System.ArgumentException    9    The culture name "-" is invalid.    System.Globalization.CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.ValidateCulturePiece(System.String, System.String, Int32, Boolean, Boolean) 
   System.Globalization.CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder..ctor(System.String, System.Globalization.CultureAndRegionModifiers) 
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.LanguageProvider.GetCultureBuilder(System.String, Boolean) 
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.LanguageProvider.IsValidLanguageName(System.String) 

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException    3    A rebuild process with the specified unique identifier does not exist.    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__174_0(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader>) 
   System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].InnerInvoke() 
   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() 
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() 
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task) 
   Sitecore.Xdb.Sql.Common.Extensions.DbCommandExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass0_0+<<ExecuteReaderWithRetryAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() 
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() 
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task) 
   Sitecore.Xdb.Sql.Common.Extensions.DbCommandExtensions+<ExecuteReaderWithRetryAsync>d__0.MoveNext() 
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() 
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task) 
   Sitecore.Xdb.Sql.Common.Extensions.SqlCommandExtensions+<ExecuteReaderWithRetryAsync>d__0.MoveNext() 
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() 
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task) 
   Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.History.SqlRebuildProcessStateDataProvider+<GetStateAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
```

Comment: What .net framework are you using?

Comment: 4.6.2 but i have installed 4.7 as well after getting this error

Comment: That is a Stack Overflow exception. Check that the template you are trying to create an item from, does not have a circular base template inheritance in place. e.g. Template B inheriting from Template A which then inherits from Template B.

Comment: @MarkCassidy - this is a fresh installation and i have not created any template. when i try to expand the tree for sample item it throws this error.

Comment: 9.0.0 or 9.0.1?

Comment: I was able to solve the issue. Unfortunately that was a mistake from my side. I was having an older version of IIS rewrite module due to which the internal url were not working properly. Once I installed version 2.1 which is a prerequisite it started working. Rewrite module being an IIS module was not giving the exact error in the event log and sitecore logs.